# Bricks split in different places of outside wall

Tags: walls

[Google drive picture attachment](https://photos.app.goo.gl/Jv6rvVFMNf4bXFPn6)

Are brick splits/cracks like these normal? Just noticed that quite a few of them are cracked in random places on outside wall. But just the bricks it self, no further vertical lines nothing
Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Are these bricks new or old?  It is not normal since it makes it easier for water(rain) to get inside them.  If in a location that freezes, the water inside the bricks will freeze and do split them much more.

Comment: I would say those are mostly cosmetic, not structural.

Comment: They are old I believe. We haven't replaced them and it isn't a new build house. What would be the options in your opinion? Replace the cracked bricks?

Comment: Probably sealing them would be cheaper/easier than replacing.  Do not know enough about brick sealing.  Is it just the odd one or quite a few.  Replacement bricks would be hard to match(looks, colour) to the older bricks.

Comment: In between not too many but also few more hence catched my eye. Okay will try to search around sealing option and will probably check up with some local experts how much it would cost if go replacing route.

Comment: This was interesting so I stepped out my front door and examined several square feet of 25 year old brick. Found at least as many imperfections in my brick work . I guess I will do .......   nothing.

Comment: That's good, in confirms what others suggested and it isn't that strange.

Comment: Please use the build in image hosting system. Not everyone can or wants to go out to a google drive location to view images.

Comment: Got it loud and clear.

Answer (score 1):

That looks pretty normal.

If the cracks join up to make lines or staircase pattern then you may have a problem with the foundation.

Comment: On the west coast US it is often from earthquakes. Even structural internal problems can cause stair step due to lateral forces.

Comment: Yes, earthquakes can damage foundations.  I didn't say a definate foundation problem.

Comment: Jason I did not say foundation’s the wave can leave the foundation intact and the damage can be just stair steps along the mortar lines. I have found this several times and repointing is all that was needed.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing unusual with the bricks in your photos.

Some of the cracks are actually from poor quality brick manufacturing.

The worst problem for brick work is when a crack line goes through the center of multiple rows or at a joint through the middle, joint, middle, this is really bad as the wall is shearing, the foundation pros are needed.

The stair step along the grout lines can have multiple causes but is usually not as severe and coming from earthquake country can be caused from a trembler.

With your photos I do not see anything of concern a few small cracks that could be repointed but nothing at this time to panic about.

I learned to take photos with a scale (tape measure/ yard stick) in view so they can be checked in a year or 3,5 years later no real change nothing to worry about.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Will do as you said and take picture with measure tape to have something to compare later on.